# Website Compatibility With Browsers

Tags: html

I have designed a website using HTML5. The website is complete and i have tested it on different browssers it is working on IE and Chrome but not in firefox. Can anyone suggest me how I  can make my website compatible to all browsers now.

Comment: use http://html5boilerplate.com/

Comment: If you did it right, it would work in Firefox too. Maybe it's just an HTML tag issue.

Answer (score 2):

Sometime you will have to check the browser and design accordingly. 
if(IE)
add this CSS
else if (Firefox)
not that but this CSS
else
other CSS

Comment: That's about as useful as the Question. I'm giving you a free point. Let's just make this the official Answer.